# Deleting copied sys and proc folders within a subdirectory in Linux

Tags: permissions

I accidentally copied the sys and proc from my root folder to a subdirectory and I'm not able to delete these directories. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my working 16.04.6:

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ ll -d /proc /sys
dr-xr-xr-x 309 root root 0 Jan  1 23:15 /proc
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root 0 Jan  1 23:15 /sys
```

Depending on how you copied them, they MAY have kept the `root:root` ownership, and probably did preserve the `dr-xr-xr-x` permissions.

So, to delete the copies, you'll have to:

```
sudo rm -rfv subdirectory/{proc,sys}
```